# creating a hanging hose with soft body

Tags: bezier-curves, physics, rigid-body-simulation, cloth-simulation, collision

I want to make a hanging hose similar to this image. I have been spending a day to find a way to archive a real rolled up hose effect. Please help guys [image]

first I made the holder (not similar to the image). Then I created a spiral(ADD-CURVE-CURVE SPIRAL-ARCHEMEDIAN). After that, I added geometry to it and softbody modifier to the spiral. And collision to the holder. Below images you can see the properties I applied to the holder and spiral.[image: softbody data][image: collision data]

This is what the result I get[image]

If anyone knows how to fix this or another way to do this(using cloth modifier)??

blender file   https://drive.google.com/file/d/1YIemo8rG1_8VPg3fQkBWYFiUwLeDPf6f/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Have you tried the usual suspects: Applied all transformations, checked face orientation? Maybe it's too heavy for the size? How big is the model? The collision often is really rebellious.

Comment: please provide blend file

Comment: blender file is in above link

Comment: It looks like from the first screenshot that the hose is already intersecting itself. That’s basically begging for soft body physics to go wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Besides the problems mentioned in the comments, there is something wrong with the spiral. The softbody simulation is very slow for some reason. The recreation of the softbody physics didn't help so I recreated the curve itself. (created a spiral with the *Extra Curves* add-on, set *Bevel > Depth* in the settings, rotated, and scaled it a bit). This fixed it.

[image: spiral]

Figuring out the right parameters for the simulation is always a guessing game.

Let's begin with the mount (*Plane*). Since you modeled it in the real-world size you need to lower the values for the *Thickness Outer* and *Inner* in the *Collision* settings. I've also doubled the *Damping* to calm down the hose (else it wiggles around):

[image: plane collision settings]

In the *Softbody* settings for the hose (*Spiral*) you need to lower the *Mass* (`0.1 kg`). Too much mass lets the hose break into the mount. Too little mass makes the hose float.

Check `[X] Goal` and set `Damping` to a value between `5` and `15`. This will make the simulation a "slow-motion" animation but "tames" the wild hose.

*Edges* has no changes at all. But check `[X] Self Collision`. The `Ball Size` value (`0.035 m`) is very important and depends on the model size. If the value is too high the hose parts spread apart/"explode". If it's too low it intersects.

[image: softbody settings]

## For Comparison

[image: cloth and softbody, start of simulation]

These models are roughly 9 times bigger and the values for the settings are higher as you can see.

The left one is a *Cloth* simulation (*Leather* preset with 0.2kg mass). It's slower than the *Softbody* simulation and requires that you convert the curve into a mesh but looks more similar to the reference. Because it's stiffer you need to model the end of the hose straight before the simulation begins so that it hangs loosely.

The softbody simulation is rather noodle-like.

[image: cloth and softbody, end of simulation]